# Pegar Itens de um Json com php

Tags: php, json

Tenho o seguinte .Json

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
  ["card-header"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
    ["raceId"]=>
    string(7) "1706057"
    ["races"]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
      ["95049"]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (6) {
        ["meeting_abandoned"]=>
        int(0)
        ["track"]=>
        string(8) "Kilkenny"
        ["races"]=>
        array(10) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706057"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(4) "8:12"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706058"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(4) "8:27"
          }
          [2]=>
          object(stdClass)#7 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706059"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(4) "8:43"
          }
          [3]=>
          object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706060"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(4) "9:02"
          }
          [4]=>
          object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706857"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(4) "9:18"
          }
          [5]=>
          object(stdClass)#10 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706858"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(4) "9:34"
          }
          [6]=>
          object(stdClass)#11 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706859"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(4) "9:52"
          }
          [7]=>
          object(stdClass)#12 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706860"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(5) "10:07"
          }
          [8]=>
          object(stdClass)#13 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706861"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(5) "10:23"
          }
          [9]=>
          object(stdClass)#14 (3) {
            ["raceId"]=>
            string(7) "1706862"
            ["raceDate"]=>
            string(10) "2019-07-03"
            ["raceTime"]=>
            string(5) "10:41"
          }
        }
        ["track_id"]=>
        string(2) "50"
        ["tv_id"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["tv_name"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
    ["courseId"]=>
    int(95049)
    ["country"]=>
    string(3) "IRE"
    ["trackAbbrName"]=>
    string(7) "K'kenny"
  }
  ["card-title"]=>
  object(stdClass)#15 (16) {
    ["postPick"]=>
    string(5) "6-5-3"
    ["napNum"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["raceSisStatusTopicD5"]=>
    string(48) "GREYHOUNDS/2019-07-03/KILKENNY/08:12/#SIS_STATUS"
    ["infoTopicD5"]=>
    string(78) "GREYHOUNDS/2019-07-03/KILKENNY/08:12/OUTRIGHT WINNER/#INFO/PREFERRED_BOOKMAKER"
    ["priceTopicD5"]=>
    string(86) "GREYHOUNDS/2019-07-03/KILKENNY/08:12/OUTRIGHT WINNER/PREFERRED_DOG/PREFERRED_BOOKMAKER"
    ["testingPriceTopic"]=>
    string(86) "GREYHOUNDS/2019-07-03/KILKENNY/08:12/OUTRIGHT WINNER/PREFERRED_DOG/PREFERRED_BOOKMAKER"
    ["distance"]=>
    int(480)
    ["raceGrade"]=>
    string(2) "A9"
    ["raceTypeDesc"]=>
    string(4) "Flat"
    ["raceDatetime"]=>
    string(10) "1562137920"
    ["raceHour"]=>
    string(2) "08"
    ["raceMin"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["reserved"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tvId"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["bagsCode"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["raceTitle"]=>
    string(6) "Race 1"
  }
  ["card-tabs"]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (20) {
    ["raceId"]=>
    string(7) "1706057"
    ["raceDate"]=>
    string(16) "2019-07-03 08:12"
    ["distance"]=>
    string(3) "480"
    ["raceStatus"]=>
    int(0)
    ["raceTitle"]=>
    string(32) "Welcome To Kilkenny Track A9 525"
    ["bagsCode"]=>
    string(1) "S"
    ["trackName"]=>
    string(8) "KILKENNY"
    ["trackCde"]=>
    string(4) "KILK"
    ["rpTrackShortName"]=>
    string(5) "Kilky"
    ["trackId"]=>
    string(2) "50"
    ["country"]=>
    string(3) "IRE"
    ["typeDesc"]=>
    string(4) "Flat"
    ["raceGrade"]=>
    string(2) "A9"
    ["selTrapNum"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["tvId"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["dangerTrapNum"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["fcastAltTrapNum"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["napNum"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["raceDateDate"]=>
    string(10) "2019-07-03"
    ["raceDateTime"]=>
    string(5) "08:12"
  }
  ["card"]=>
  object(stdClass)#17 (1) {
    ["dogs"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#18 (28) {
        ["dogId"]=>
        string(6) "528848"
        ["trackId"]=>
        string(2) "50"
        ["trapNum"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["dogName"]=>
        string(14) "Flexible Pango"
        ["dogColor"]=>
        string(2) "BK"
        ["dogSex"]=>
        string(1) "B"
        ["forecastComment"]=>
        string(42) "Been battered around lately, due some luck"
        ["chanceOfWin"]=>
        float(30.72)
        ["trainerName"]=>
        string(9) "M Kennedy"
        ["trainerLocation"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["forecast"]=>
        string(3) "5/1"
        ["topSpeed"]=>
        string(2) "93"
        ["wideYn"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["handicapMetre"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["diffusionName"]=>
        string(14) "FLEXIBLE_PANGO"
        ["spotlightComment"]=>
        string(42) "Been battered around lately, due some luck"
        ["nonRunner"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["reserved"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["isVacant"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["dateOfBirth"]=>
        string(6) "1Sep15"
        ["brt"]=>
        string(5) "30.57"
        ["bestTimeGrade"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["bestTimeGradeDate"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["sire"]=>
        string(12) "Farloe Tango"
        ["dam"]=>
        string(13) "Flexible Dora"
        ["birthMonYY"]=>
        string(5) "Sep15"
        ["dateOfSeason"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shortForm"]=>
        string(5) "53355"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#19 (28) {
        ["dogId"]=>
        string(6) "532977"
        ["trackId"]=>
        string(2) "50"
        ["trapNum"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["dogName"]=>
        string(13) "Bradys Choice"
        ["dogColor"]=>
        string(2) "BK"
        ["dogSex"]=>
        string(1) "B"
        ["forecastComment"]=>
        string(51) "Finding trouble, not showcasing ability as a result"
        ["chanceOfWin"]=>
        float(30.78)
        ["trainerName"]=>
        string(9) "M Fortune"
        ["trainerLocation"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["forecast"]=>
        string(3) "5/1"
        ["topSpeed"]=>
        string(2) "91"
        ["wideYn"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["handicapMetre"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["diffusionName"]=>
        string(13) "BRADYS_CHOICE"
        ["spotlightComment"]=>
        string(51) "Finding trouble, not showcasing ability as a result"
        ["nonRunner"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["reserved"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["isVacant"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["dateOfBirth"]=>
        string(7) "11Jan18"
        ["brt"]=>
        string(5) "30.67"
        ["bestTimeGrade"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["bestTimeGradeDate"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["sire"]=>
        string(13) "Ballymac Eske"
        ["dam"]=>
        string(12) "Marinas Blue"
        ["birthMonYY"]=>
        string(5) "Jan18"
        ["dateOfSeason"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shortForm"]=>
        string(5) "T5666"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#20 (28) {
        ["dogId"]=>
        string(6) "528978"
        ["trackId"]=>
        string(2) "50"
        ["trapNum"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["dogName"]=>
        string(13) "Littlest Hobo"
        ["dogColor"]=>
        string(3) "WBK"
        ["dogSex"]=>
        string(1) "B"
        ["forecastComment"]=>
        string(54) "Learning twists and turns of track, may still run well"
        ["chanceOfWin"]=>
        float(30.42)
        ["trainerName"]=>
        string(9) "D Fogarty"
        ["trainerLocation"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["forecast"]=>
        string(3) "4/1"
        ["topSpeed"]=>
        string(2) "99"
        ["wideYn"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["handicapMetre"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["diffusionName"]=>
        string(13) "LITTLEST_HOBO"
        ["spotlightComment"]=>
        string(54) "Learning twists and turns of track, may still run well"
        ["nonRunner"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["reserved"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["isVacant"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["dateOfBirth"]=>
        string(6) "1May17"
        ["brt"]=>
        string(5) "30.31"
        ["bestTimeGrade"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["bestTimeGradeDate"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["sire"]=>
        string(14) "Sidarian Blaze"
        ["dam"]=>
        string(14) "Miss Precedent"
        ["birthMonYY"]=>
        string(5) "May17"
        ["dateOfSeason"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shortForm"]=>
        string(5) "532T3"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(stdClass)#21 (28) {
        ["dogId"]=>
        string(6) "532964"
        ["trackId"]=>
        string(2) "50"
        ["trapNum"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["dogName"]=>
        string(9) "Amwhatiam"
        ["dogColor"]=>
        string(2) "BE"
        ["dogSex"]=>
        string(1) "B"
        ["forecastComment"]=>
        string(49) "Luck tends to even itself out, due a change of it"
        ["chanceOfWin"]=>
        float(30.51)
        ["trainerName"]=>
        string(11) "S O'Donnell"
        ["trainerLocation"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["forecast"]=>
        string(3) "7/2"
        ["topSpeed"]=>
        string(2) "96"
        ["wideYn"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["handicapMetre"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["diffusionName"]=>
        string(9) "AMWHATIAM"
        ["spotlightComment"]=>
        string(49) "Luck tends to even itself out, due a change of it"
        ["nonRunner"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["reserved"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["isVacant"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["dateOfBirth"]=>
        string(7) "12Sep17"
        ["brt"]=>
        string(4) "30.4"
        ["bestTimeGrade"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["bestTimeGradeDate"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["sire"]=>
        string(16) "Superior Product"
        ["dam"]=>
        string(12) "Aclamon Jill"
        ["birthMonYY"]=>
        string(5) "Sep17"
        ["dateOfSeason"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shortForm"]=>
        string(5) "TTT64"
      }
      [4]=>
      object(stdClass)#22 (28) {
        ["dogId"]=>
        string(6) "528832"
        ["trackId"]=>
        string(2) "50"
        ["trapNum"]=>
        string(1) "5"
        ["dogName"]=>
        string(16) "Heyisntthatright"
        ["dogColor"]=>
        string(2) "BK"
        ["dogSex"]=>
        string(1) "B"
        ["forecastComment"]=>
        string(47) "Five alive? Must be paw perfect to avoid a bang"
        ["chanceOfWin"]=>
        float(30.33)
        ["trainerName"]=>
        string(14) "M Bergin-Flynn"
        ["trainerLocation"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["forecast"]=>
        string(3) "7/2"
        ["topSpeed"]=>
        string(3) "100"
        ["wideYn"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["handicapMetre"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["diffusionName"]=>
        string(16) "HEYISNTTHATRIGHT"
        ["spotlightComment"]=>
        string(47) "Five alive? Must be paw perfect to avoid a bang"
        ["nonRunner"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["reserved"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["isVacant"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["dateOfBirth"]=>
        string(7) "15Aug17"
        ["brt"]=>
        string(5) "30.13"
        ["bestTimeGrade"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["bestTimeGradeDate"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["sire"]=>
        string(14) "Barefoot James"
        ["dam"]=>
        string(8) "Hey Ruby"
        ["birthMonYY"]=>
        string(5) "Aug17"
        ["dateOfSeason"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shortForm"]=>
        string(5) "44336"
      }
      [5]=>
      object(stdClass)#23 (28) {
        ["dogId"]=>
        string(6) "533139"
        ["trackId"]=>
        string(2) "50"
        ["trapNum"]=>
        string(1) "6"
        ["dogName"]=>
        string(14) "Kilbreedy Hulk"
        ["dogColor"]=>
        string(2) "BK"
        ["dogSex"]=>
        string(1) "D"
        ["forecastComment"]=>
        string(45) "Being backed with good reason, leading player"
        ["chanceOfWin"]=>
        float(30.29)
        ["trainerName"]=>
        string(8) "F Hickey"
        ["trainerLocation"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["forecast"]=>
        string(3) "9/4"
        ["topSpeed"]=>
        string(2) "99"
        ["wideYn"]=>
        string(1) "M"
        ["handicapMetre"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["diffusionName"]=>
        string(14) "KILBREEDY_HULK"
        ["spotlightComment"]=>
        string(45) "Being backed with good reason, leading player"
        ["nonRunner"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["reserved"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["isVacant"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["dateOfBirth"]=>
        string(7) "21Oct17"
        ["brt"]=>
        string(5) "30.23"
        ["bestTimeGrade"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["bestTimeGradeDate"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["sire"]=>
        string(12) "Farloe Blitz"
        ["dam"]=>
        string(14) "Garryglass Ros"
        ["birthMonYY"]=>
        string(5) "Oct17"
        ["dateOfSeason"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["shortForm"]=>
        string(5) "T6326"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Estou com dificuldades em pegar itens pertencentes a apenas um objeto especificamente...

Por exemplo, tenho o objeto [card-header], [card-title], [card-tabs] e [card]...

Quando acesso por exemplo, o `[card-title]->postPick`, tenho o seguinte problema...

Se acesso assim:

```
foreach($itens->card-title as $dados){
  echo $dados->postPick;
}
```

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Caso não oriente o objeto e acesse assim:

```
foreach($itens as $dados){
 echo "Resultado".$dados->postPick."<br>";
}
```

Eu imprimo os dados e vejo que o `foreach()` percorreu todo o json, e imprime um "resultado" para cada objeto... por exemplo...

```
Resultado:       (nao presente no [card-header]
Resultado: 6-5-3 (presente apenas no [card-title]
Resultado:       (não presente no [card-tabs]
Resultado:       (não presente no card)
```

teoricamente deveria aparecer apenas o segundo resultado, pois é o único lugar onde está presente o objeto...

Resumindo, como posso acessar separadamente esses objetos sendo que recebo esse warning quando tento orientar dentro do `foreach()`?  Será que o problema pode ser o hífen no nome do objeto, tipo **[card-title]** e causa esse erro de sintaxe? Eu fiz todo processo com o objeto **[card]** e funcionou perfeitamente, então estou crendo nisso...

ps: Não quero tranformar o json em array, tentei e tive mais dificuldade ainda.

Comment: Porque você não muda de "card-header" para "cardHeader", e "card-title" para "cardTitle", etc... da forma que você está usando pode dar problemas quando se usa objeto, é só usar um alias, no caso...

Comment: Acho que é algo assim para funcionar:

`if (count($seu_objeto->{"card-header"}->raceId->races->95049->meeting_abandoned->races)) {
    $races = $seu_objeto->{"card-header"}->raceId->races->95049->meeting_abandoned->races;
    foreach($races as $race) {

      $race->raceId;
      ...
    }
} `

Comment: [Veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/Sf2ahj)

Comment: Eu até tentei retirar o hífen, mas acontece que o json é dinâmico e pego de outro servidor...Mas de toda forma, consegui me livrar dos valores duplicados e nulos da seguinte forma `if($dados->raceId != NULL){$raceid = $dados->raceId; }`,  jogando os valores não nulos para uma variável, mas, vou tentar fazer do jeito que você propôs, não conhecia! –